# SQL NULL Value to = A Sequential Number, Help!

Tags: sql-server

I have upgraded a database at work from a poorly designed Microsoft Access database to a SQL database.

The previous system allowed `NULL` values and duplicates to be inserted into a field that should not allow `NULL` values or duplicates.  Since the existing data already has some entries that are `NULL`, I cannot set `NOT NULL` constraints.

My solution would be to use a sequential operator.  For instance, `NULL` data would be changed to a sequential number that system administrators would know was a bogus number starting at something like 999999900, incrementing up from there. There are only 250 records that would require updating.

To make things more interesting this field is not a integer type, its a `VARCHAR` type as it is a Hardware ID.  The existing data contains both alpha and numeric data.

Any advice on how to update these `NULL` values using an incremental ID?

Comment: HI Marian, I believe the Nvarchar field size is 10 or 15, If I used GUIDs would mean changing the field size to 32 if I remember correctly, plus GUIDs are not always generated randomly although I'm sure your agree the chance of the system generating a duplicate ID String is near impossible. Good Idea this may have to be my second option.

Answer (score 3):

Well, starting with a numerical example pulled from the link at the bottom and then just changing the variable type from int to varchar() works because there is implicit conversion due to the math expression I assume. The field "id" is also a varchar().

```
  declare
      @start varchar(30) = 100000000;

   update t
      set @start = id = @start - 1
     from #TheTable t
    where id is null;
```

I came up with this mess before I realized the that the varchar() performed auto conversion. It requires a primary key (pk) but doesn't require a local variable.

```
  update t
     set id = r.NextId
    from #TheTable t
    join (select pk,
                 10000000 - row_number() over (order by rand()) as NextId
            from #TheTable
           where id is null) r
      on r.pk = t.pk
   where t.id is null;
```

(Above example was edited to fix bug after receiving comment)

[Numeric Solution and many replies that may have an better answer](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/02/28/sql-auto-increment.aspx)

Update - Responding to comments:  To patch them from 9's to sequential.  Please double check the number of 9's, your comment listed the wrong number I think.

```
declare
   @fromValue varchar(30) = '9999999';  -- 7 nines

UPDATE t
   SET HardwareNumber = r.NextID 
  FROM tblAsset t
  JOIN (select Asset_ID,
               10000000 - ROW NUMBER() over (order by RAND()) AS NextID 
          FROM tblAsset 
         WHERE HardwareNumber = @fromValue) r
    on r.Asset_ID = t.Asset_ID
 WHERE t.HardwareNumber = @fromValue;
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option which is worth considering in my opinion. On SQLServer you can have a filtered unique index , `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ..... WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL`. Then you just need to ensure that new applications don't insert null into this column, and you don't have to generate any bogus numbers that potentially may cause conflicts with new data.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue:

```
UPDATE r
SET HardwareNumber = r.NextID 
FROM (
   SELECT 
      999999899 + ROW NUMBER() over (order by HardwareNumber) AS NextID,
      HardwareNumber 
   FROM tblAsset 
   WHERE HardwareNumber is NULL
) r;
```